# how to get Twist.h file for joystick controled turtlesim?

Tags: ros, joy-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi. i am following joy node tutorial. the tutorial is for ros hydro and in ros build. i want to use that code in ros indigo. i changed the code accordingly but running error shows Twist.h file not found. how to get it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239007/how-to-get-twist.h-file-for-joystick-controled-turtlesim?/) by [Arpitsoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/27421/arpitsoni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2016-07-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to add a dependency for geometry_msgs to your package and CMakeLists.txt.

See the message tutorials for how to do that.

---

Originally posted by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) with karma: 476 on 2016-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1